# Disable and display all hyperlinks in Outlook messages

Tags: vba, hyperlink, outlook, phishing

I need to rollout an Outlook VBA macro to disable and display all hyperlinks in email messages.

Optimally all hyperlinks would be disabled from being clickable and for text that have a “hidden” link the link would be disabled and following the text (still in blue) the link would be displayed within square brackets.

I have a lot of Excel VBA experience but almost no Outlook VBA experience. I’m surprised this code isn’t all over the place but after a week of searching I’ve found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to retrieve the HTML body (`MailItem.HTMLBody` property), load it into an instance of the `IHTMLDocument2` object, loop thorough the links collection and modify the links. You will then need to retrieve the modified HTML body and set the `MailItem.HTMLBody` property.

You can of course do your own parsing by looking at all the `<a>` tags in the HTML body instead of using the `IHTMLDocument2` object.

Comment: Are the messages always in HTML? I was looking into using Word.Application and Word.Document. Then I was considering AutoFormatReplaceHyperlinks. Is MailItem.HTMLBody available with all messages?  Could this be as simple as replacing all <a> and </a> tags?

Comment: Yes, MailItem.HTMLBody will always be available, even for a plain text message. You can use MailItem.GetInspector and then Inspector.WordEditor (returns Word.Document), but it is pretty heavy and I would not recommend doing that for a large number of messages.